# OpenCV - System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException Visual C++ Exception CLR Project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I've been struggling with this problem for about three hours and honestly I'm tired...

I have no idea what I can be doing wrong.

This is the function I've got:

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        std::vector<Mat> images;
        std::vector<int> labels;

        std::vector<cv::String> filenames;
        glob("Dataface/*.jpg", filenames, false);

        if (filenames.size() == (size_t)0) {
            MessageBox::Show("La carpeta está vacía.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
            return;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
            images.push_back(imread(filenames[i]));
            labels.push_back((int)i);
        }

        Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();

        model->train(images, labels);

        Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Germán Aguilera\\Desktop\\Christina.jpg");

        int prediction = model->predict(img);

        //MessageBox::Show(prediction.ToString());

        //rModel = &model;

        MessageBox::Show("El programa ya ha sido entrenado.", "Reconocimiento facial", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
    }
```

The line that is throwing the exception is:

```
int prediction = model->predict(img);
```

But why is that?
I didnt have any problem with:

```
model->train(images, labels);
```

So I just copied and pasted into another folder a process image to use the predict function to check the results out, but I got that exception.

Comment: During debugging with visual studio check console output to see if anything hints toward the real cause. SEHException just shows that an unmanaged exception has occured which CLR doesn't know anything about. (Its from OpenCV side)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice. At least I can know what's going on. xD I hope I can fix it soon. Thanks. ^^